# Binding к ListBox вместо списка строк выводит список из букв строки первого элемента

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Binding работет, но не так как надо. вместо списка строк выводит список из букв строки первого элемента. не могу понять в чем проблема, на сколько знаю ListBox не должен строку рабивать на буквы, а из колекции строки целиком вставлять.

код класса

```
public class ConnectionString
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IPAdress { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Podrazdelenie { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

разметка Page

```
<StackPanel>
        <WrapPanel Margin="5">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Name}"/>
        </WrapPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="IP адрес" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBox Template="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding IPAdress}"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Путь до БД" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBox Template="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Path}"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Код подразделения" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBox Template="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Podrazdelenie}"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Логин" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBox Template="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Login}"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Пароль" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBox Template="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Password}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

код Page

```
    public partial class Settings : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<ConnectionString> dbConnection { get; set; }

    public Settings()
    {
        dbConnection = new ObservableCollection<ConnectionString>()
        {
            new ConnectionString(){ IPAdress="192", Path="dssfsdgfdg", Name="gjkbrkb", Podrazdelenie="654stgdsrt4", Login="sysdba", Password="nretn"},
            new ConnectionString(){ IPAdress="11572", Path="iz8sduujs", Name="zxdcgdrgy", Podrazdelenie="4356jsahjh8", Login="sysdba1", Password="jawqesdfhn"}
        };

        InitializeComponent();



        this.DataContext = dbConnection;
    }
   }
```

Comment: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Name}"/>` ? В качестве ` ItemsSource` должна быть коллекция, а не отдельное свойство элемента коллекции. А для отображения свойств нужно использовать `DataTemplate` внутри листбокса.

Comment: тогда должно быть что то такое?

Comment: <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding dbConnection}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Так почему то не работает binding